# How can we stop a process like shell_exec() or exec() by a click envent from an other page?

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a website where different external program can be executed depending on the option chose by the user. 
One of them takes more than 30s (time needed to collect data from sensors).

How can I allow the user to stop the execution by using a button on another page?

In details, I proceed this way :

When the user chose this option, an Ajax request is sent to the server :

```
$('#start_2').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
   var data="opt="+1+"delay="+$('input[name=delay_acquisition]:checked').val();

$("#main_content").load("../dist/waitingPage.php"); //show countdown during process

$.ajax({
  url:'dataProcessing.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:data,
  async: true,
  success:function(){
    alert("succes start stabilo");
    $("#main_content").load("../dist/results.php");
  },
  error:function(){
    alert("The submission encounter an error");
  }
});
```

});

dataProcessing.php :

```
session_start();

error_reporting(-1);
set_time_limit(20);

$delay = $_POST['delay'];
$_SESSION['delay'] = $delay;

chdir("executables");

//Start acquisition
$cmd = shell_exec("python test.py $delay");

$PID = shell_exec("nohup $cmd > /dev/null & echo $!");

$_SESSION['pid_py'] = $PID;
```

...

waitingPage.php : countdown and stop button.

I have tried to execute a script contening :
    `shell_exec("sudo kill -s 9 $_SESSION['pid_py']");`
and
    `shell_exec("sudo killall python");`

But it didn't work.

I have also tried to open a process in "dataProcessing.php" to use proc_terminate(), but I don't know if is it possible to get a resource from another page (At least I didn't manage to do it! )

I work with Xampp on Ubuntu (Apache server) if that can help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
session_start();
set_time_limit(20);

$delay = $_POST['delay'];

chdir("executables");

$PID = shell_exec("python test.py $delay >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$!");

$_SESSION['pid_py'] = $PID;
```

Another:

```
session_start();
posix_kill($_SESSION['pid_py'], SIGTERM);
// or
shell_exec("kill {$_SESSION['pid_py']}");
```

Comment: Thank's. I've tried both but still not working. ( adding `shell_exec("python test.py $delay");` otherwise the .py is not executed). In the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.posix-kill.php) Someone said " The $sig parameter cannot be one of the PCNTL signals constants if you are running your script from the browser (ie. as an apache process)" Can we use other signals constants ?